# Change Yahoo! profile picture

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-account

I am a frequent user of Yahoo! comments but I don't know how to change my profile picture. On the profile edit page you can change your nickname and above all that your default picture is shown but no option to change it. Am I missing something? How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The ability to change ones profile picture went away when http://profiles.yahoo.com shut down in January, 2015. They've not introduced a new method to change your profile picture.

From [Yahoo! help](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN25611.html?impressions=true):

**Update your Account picture**

> Yahoo Profile (profile.yahoo.com) no longer exists. **But don't worry** - your comments on various Yahoo properties didn't disappear! Most relevant settings are now in your account settings. We simply removed the ability to view public profiles and the “about me” and “my interests” sections, but you can still post comments on the various Yahoo properties and your Yahoo nickname and profile pic still exist.
>
> > **Coming soon!** - This feature may not be available on your account just yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research about this, and apparently Yahoo decided to take away the ability to change anything on your profile in Jan 2015. Before, you could use http://profiles.yahoo.com/ , but now it's gone.

Sources: Quora

Comment: No need to search anywhere else, Yahoo! has mentioned this on their help page- _This feature may not be available on your account just yet_. Look at my [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97975/87130).